# Efecto de zoom y posición absoluta on mouse move/mouse over

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hola queria saber como puedo hacer un efecto igual o parecido al de esta pagina http://shop.fisbon.com/es/home/47080-cubritas-gotas-mediana.html cuando se pasa el mouse por encima de la imagen del producto se hace como un zoom y si moves el mouse se mueve la imagen

Comment: jQzoom Evolution Library v2.3

Comment: muchisimas gracias aloMalbarez, no se como poner tu respuesta como la correcta jeje soy nuevo :s